# kube-Prometheus-stack - Grafana pod stuck at "CrashloopBackoff"

Tags: devops, prometheus, grafana, monitoring, kube-prometheus-stack

Trying to install kube-prometheus-stack (39.8.0) and everything went well, now there is a requirement - where grafana pod needs to have a persistent vol with oci-fss as a storage class, below is my values.yaml file.

```
grafana:
  initChownData:
    enabled: false
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    type: pvc
    storageClassName: oci-fss
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    size: 50Gi
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
```

Grafana pod status is:

```
pod/prometheus-grafana-54cdc8774f-blfqx                      2/3     CrashLoopBackOff
```

Grafana pod logs:

```
ubectl logs -f  pod/prometheus-grafana-54cdc8774f-blfqx -n prometheus
Defaulted container "grafana-sc-dashboard" out of: grafana-sc-dashboard, grafana-sc-datasources, grafana
{"time": "2022-11-11T08:07:40.625012+00:00", "level": "INFO", "msg": "Starting collector"}
{"time": "2022-11-11T08:07:40.625190+00:00", "level": "WARNING", "msg": "No folder annotation was provided, defaulting to k8s-sidecar-target-directory"}
{"time": "2022-11-11T08:07:40.625329+00:00", "level": "INFO", "msg": "Loading incluster config ..."}
{"time": "2022-11-11T08:07:40.626083+00:00", "level": "INFO", "msg": "Config for cluster api at 'https://10.96.0.1:443' loaded..."}
{"time": "2022-11-11T08:07:40.626199+00:00", "level": "INFO", "msg": "Unique filenames will not be enforced."}
{"time": "2022-11-11T08:07:40.626283+00:00", "level": "INFO", "msg": "5xx response content will not be enabled."}
```

Comment: it was filesystem storage issue, Grafana container was not able to write it's configuration to the storage, we can mark this as resolved

Answer (score -1):

it was filesystem storage issue, Grafana container was not able to write it's configuration to the storage, we can mark this as resolved

Comment: I see grafana at OS level has a user with id 472 but /var/ is owned by root and only root can write something into /var, is it a problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please consider adding more information for the actual resolution. The current is just a lead and not an actual answer.